# Jquery Chosen Plugin Multi Language Support

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-chosen

I'm using Jquery Chosen Plugin ( http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ )

I need Turkish language support for chosen plugin. When i search "izmir" it says "no results match" cause "i" is lowercase and my text is "İzmir".

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`i` and `İ` are different Unicode values that are not related in Regex like latin `i` and `I`. Chosen uses Regex to filter the results:

```
regex = new RegExp(regexAnchor + searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
zregex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
```

(From Chosen's source on github)

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) javascript's RegExp lacks sophisticated Unicode support so I don't think that it would match it without extra code to convert the `İ` to `I` which could be matched. There's a [pull request](http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/628) also that would allow the code to determine the matching to be run by server side libraries (with better Unicode support) that you could put your support behind if you don't want to/have time to implement your own code.